# Visual Studio не видит GetProcessHandleByHwnd

Tags: c++, winapi

*Visual Studio 2022* при включенном стандарте *с++20* и включенном заголовке "windows.h" не видит функцию *GetProcessHandleByHwnd*.

Код:

```cpp
    #include <windows.h>

    int main()
    {
      auto hWnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "");
      auto pHandle = GetProcessHandleFromHwnd(hWnd);

      return 0;
    }
```

В чем может быть причина? Все останое из библиотеки видит, в т.ч. и указанную FindWindowA

Upd:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что значит "не видит"? не компилируется или красное подчёркивание?

Comment: а может не линкуется.

Comment: @PavelGridin не видит - значит красное подчеркивание. Такой функции якобы нет. В документации не сказано, чтобы она по какой-то причине не должна была быть

Comment: это наверное сбоит IntelliSense, обычное дело, попробуте выйти из VS и удалить директорию `.vs` - это его кэш

Comment: @PavelGridin это не IntelliSense, я добавил скрин. Линкер тоже меня посылает, кэш удалил на всякий - не помогло

Comment: и правда нет, вот пишут, что устарела https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397012/how-to-include-oleacc-for-getprocesshandlefromhwnd-visual-c

Comment: @PavelGridin интересно, а в доке ничего про это не сказано

Comment: да не сказано, когда-то давно пользовалься этой функцией, но вообще WinAPI MS уже как-то подзабросил  с тех пор как пошло у них .net,c#